# Is it possible to add a custom hover color to Raised Buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Working on a project that is using the Material-UI library of components and I've gotten a request for a custom button hover color that is outside of the normal convention of the MUI theme.

I found this relevant block of code in the Raised Button source, https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/RaisedButton/RaisedButton.js#L98. Setting a custom labelColor does change the hover state, but that still does not satisfy my current need to have the button hover color something different than that of the label color.

```
overlay: {
  height: buttonHeight,
  borderRadius: borderRadius,
  backgroundColor: (state.keyboardFocused || state.hovered) && !disabled &&
    fade(labelColor, amount),
  transition: transitions.easeOut(),
  top: 0,
},
```

Is there a way to override the overlay background color some other way so that I can use a separate custom color?

To clarify I'm looking to do this using inline styling or through overriding a prop on the button.  Appending a class and using external CSS is not an option.

Comment: When you say ,"does not satisfy my current need", can you clarify what exactly your needs are? Do you need to have the label color and hover color to be different things?

Comment: Yes, the label color needs to be different that button background color on hover.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it by giving a `className` prop to `RaisedButton` component and specifying `:hover` attribute in css with `!important` directive.

In your component:

```
...
<RaisedButton className="my-button" />
...
```

In your css:

```
.my-button :hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to reply.  I've made an edit to my original question to clarify the method in which I'm trying to solve the issue.  I believe this method would technically work but I'm trying to accomplish this using the same convention as the rest of the project which would be setting the styling inline or by overriding a prop on the component.

Comment: I've recently worked with material-ui and we were unable to change the styles from a single point. Sometimes we override them with custom theme, sometimes we used inline styles and in the last option we used this method. Material ui is not that flexible when it comes to changing the styles.

Answer (score 0):

For raised button use this prop hoverColor so it will be something like

```
<RaisedButton 
   label="Default" 
   hoverColor={"#00ff00"} 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the render function of the RaisedButton, the `overlay` style object is overridden with the `overlayStyle` prop. (The relevant excerpt is below).

```
<div
  ref="overlay"
  style={prepareStyles(Object.assign(styles.overlay, overlayStyle))}
>
  {enhancedButtonChildren}
</div>
```

This means you can set the background color by setting the `backgroundColor` of the `overlayStyle` prop. I think the second piece of the puzzle is to set the `onMouseLeave` and `onMouseEnter` events, and manage the current background color yourself, by changing the color whenever the mouse enters or leaves the button area.

Unfortunately, it looks like the keyboard focus events don't have a hook exposed in the MaterialUI API, so you won't be able to handle that case without modifying the library.

This might be something worth submitting a pull request to MaterialUI if you go the route of modifying the library.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy solution :

```
.yourButtonClass{
  color: aColor !important;
  &>span{
    color: anotherColor;
  }
}
```

You apply the color to your button which change the label and the overlay color, and then you put your label in a span for which you specify whatever color you want the text to be.
That way your background, label and overlay can be different colors :)

can also be written in the style attribute of the respective tags:

```
<md-button class="md-raised" style="color: aColor !important">
    <span style="color: anotherColor">yourLabel</span>
</md-button>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use jquery to simply remove class and addClass

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#test').hover(
     function(){ $(this).addClass('redclass') },
     function(){ $(this).removeClass('overlay') }
   )
 });
```

'#test represent the id and .test represent the class of the element you're trying to manipulate.

Comment: jQuery and React don't mix well.