# How apply style for class child in override theme?

Tags: reactjs, themes, overriding, classname

How apply style for class child in override theme?

I have this code

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root-359 MuiToggleButton-root-630 MuiToggleButton-selected-632" tabindex="0" type="button" value="1">
   <span class="MuiToggleButton-label-633">Jan</span>
   <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-549"></span>
</button>
```

Here I have 3 css class (MuiButtonBase-root, MuiToggleButton-root and MuiToggleButton-selected)

So I need to apply a custom color to label inside "selected" class. I tried this override in my theme

```
MuiToggleButton: {
  root:{
    backgroundColor: '#5f5f5f'
  },
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: '#a1b0e2a8 !important',
    label: { //this not apply to "label" inside "selected" parent
      color: '#0000ff !important'
    }
  },
  label: {
    selected: { //this not work too
      color: '#ff0000 !important'
    },
    color: '#ffffff' //this apply to all MuiToggleButton-label css class
  }
}
```

But after run "label" inside "selected" is not recognized, only "label" white.  selected > label not work.

I look explication for this but only found css styles applied directly to the component or js code for this.

There any way for do this or is better apply the old css (file) way?

Using css file this work

```
button[class*="MuiToggleButton-selected"]  span[class^="MuiToggleButton-label"]{
  color: #0000ff;
}
```

I appreciate any resource (book, tutorial, etc) for giving me more knowledge about this.

Tks for advance

Comment: can you please share the code ?

Comment: sorry, code updated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458150/is-it-possible-to-add-a-custom-hover-color-to-raised-buttons?rq=1)

```
selected: {
   backgroundColor: '#a1b0e2a8 !important',
   '&>span': { // I need put > after &
      color: '#0000ff !important'
   }
},
```